# active_admin login failure after deploying succed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I use active_admin in local environment and it works fine.
I can login as adminuser after executing "rake db:seed".

(here is my seed.rb file)
AdminUser.create!(email: '1@1', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456') if Rails.env.development?

However in production environment, I can't access to active_admin page as admin_user.
I already tried "rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production" but it's not working.

(here is my seed.rb file in production mode)
AdminUser.create!(email: '1@1', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456') if Rails.env.production?

(here is my logs)
[image: error log here!]

Anyone plz help thanks!

Comment: Is the `production mode` on another machine, or are you testing production mode on your local host? How did you start your production rails server?

Comment: I tested on aws ec2 computer so it's production mode on another machine.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would then try adding an AdminUser through the rails console on your production environment. Can you access the rails console in that environment?